# Google Chart with Modal implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-visualization

on click of a slice of pie chart open a modal in bootstrap, JavaScript, jQuery any language.
Here is my code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phEGB.png)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What have you tried? I can see a chart but nothing that has anything to do with a modal or a click event.

Comment: I want to open a modal when I click on a slice of pie chart

Comment: I didn't get any solution for that.

Comment: Is there any way to do that @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I would like to have a modal pop up when I click a slice in the charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Google Chart [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity), you have to add a listner to the chart. In your specific case you would need handle the select event. Sample code is given on the website. Below is the code from the documentation.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2],
        ['Commute', 2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
      };

      // The select handler. Call the chart's getSelection() method
      function selectHandler() {
        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
        if (selectedItem) {
          var task = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
          alert('The user selected ' + task);
        }
      }

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      // Listen for the 'select' event, and call my function selectHandler() when
      // the user selects something on the chart.
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit: I have added a working example with alert. It gives the selected task  you can easily edit according to your requirement.

Comment: I have 4 slice of pie chart how do I implement different modal for different slices